# how update visual studio 2008 standard Edition to visual studio 2008 sp1 standard Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I need update my visual studio  2008 standard to sp1 
I'm not mean express edition I need uprate standard version because sql server 2008 not
fully support for vs2008 old version how can do this I have update .net framework 3.5 sp1
but it's not i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en).